# If $g'$ and $f$ are same signed and $f' = 0$ when $g = 1$, must $g' = 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions such that $f(0) = 0$, $g(0) = 1$, and

- $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: g' > 0\} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: f> 0\}$
- $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: g' < 0\} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: f < 0\}$
- when $x$ is such that $g(x) = 1$, then $f'(x) = 0$.

Must $g' = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: domain is assumed to be all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=1+x^2$ and $f(x)=x^3$. Then $g'>0$ and $f'>0$ iff $x>0$, $g'<0$ and $f'<0$ iff $x<0$, $g(x)=1$ only for $x=0$ and there we have $f'(0)=0$.